# How can I dynamically create a new .java file from a Java program?

Tags: java, reflection

I want to create a one .java from the Java program.  When I run the program, automatically one Java file will created in my project, and also create some run time (dynamic) variable in that file.  How can I do this?

I know for this I have to use a Reflection API like `Class` and `Method`, but what are the methods in `Class` and `Method` to do this?

Comment: What is the _problem_ you need to solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot create new classes or methods using the reflection APIs.  They are not designed for this.  (The `Class` and `Method` APIs are for performing operations on object instances in a dynamic fashion.)

If you want to create new code on the fly, there are two basic approaches to doing this:

1. Generate Java source code, write it to a file, use the Java compiler to compile it to a bytecode file, and then load the bytecodes.  (There are standard APIs for running the Java compiler within the JVM of a running application.)
2. Use [BCEL](http://jakarta.apache.org/bcel/) or equivalent to construct a bytecode file from scratch, and then load the bytecodes.

Both approaches are tricky and computationally expensive.  The BCEL approach is particularly tricky because you need to understand a lot about the JVM to do the job.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently you want to create a new class at Runtime and use it. You can sure create a `.java`file, compile it and load it from a custom class loader but that's probably not the best/easiest thing to do. Here are a bunch of solutions:

1. First of all if you want to extend an interface, you can use the [Proxy](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html) from the Java Reflection API.
2. It you want to extend a class rather than implements an interface or create a class out of the blue you need to use a library to create bytecode. You can find a bunch of them on http://www.java-opensource.com/open-source/bytecode-libraries.html. Among these libraries I like [javassist](http://labs.jboss.com/javassist/) mainly because it is the only library to my knowledge letting you enter Java code directly rather than bytecode.
3. A last solution should be to use a framework like Groovy or BSH to interpret pseudo-java code.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't generate new `.java` files using Reflection. You could perhaps create a new class, and use this class, in runtime, but you can't write that class out to file in the form of a .java source file.

Have a look at the JustAdd framework for instance. This framework solves this type of problems IIRC.

Comment: ok ... so if .java file is created and now i want to create a run time (dynamically) method or variable in to that .java file .... so how can i do this.... ?

Comment: Well, there are a few tricks. Have a look at [JRebel](http://www.zeroturnaround.com/jrebel/features/) for instance.

Comment: To create a `Method` object out of thin air, I'd suspect you need to construct the actual bytecode for that method somehow (for instance using teh ASM framework), and load it through a class loader. How to attach it to an existing `Class` I don't know.

Comment: Technically it might be a correct answer, but this is just so unnatural to do something like this in java. (especially writing the file part. May be will work for some code generation use case.) In that case, he can even leverage already existing code generation tool like Spring ROO.

Answer (score 0):

Java is a strongly typed language( As opposed to a weakly typed language). Simply put you need to have a Class (prototype) to create a instance of object. What you are trying to do is not natural in java (or any strongly typed language).

If you have to have this functionality in java, you need to use groovy. Groovy is a dynamic language that can run in Java JVM. You need to check Expandos in groovy.(ofcourse it still will not create a .java file).