# Creating a wrapper class to capture method execution time

Tags: java, wrapper

For my assignment  I have to create a program that wraps a class into another class file(clsB.java). I provide it with the name of my basic class (cls.java) and it wraps all of the methods in a way that they count time that had passed while they were working. It should look like this:

```
int get(int arg) {
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    parent::get(...) = 
    System.out.println("Time passed = " + System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime);
}
```

I have tried using Class object and extracting all parts of cls.java code in order to simply write them into a file I create but I couldn't find any way to add methods that have any arguments. Is there any way to make it my way or should I search for some other idea? Thank you for all the answers in advance :)

Comment: This is not clear.  Do you need to write a new class by hand (in which case you just create wrapper methods  for every base class method), or do you want to do this dynamically at run-time, using reflection?

Comment: I think he/she is seeking to modify the methods at runtime to wrap them in a sort of counter class which will determine method execution time.  Is this correct?

Comment: Sounds like a job for a `Proxy` instance.  See [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Proxy.html)

Comment: The program has to dynamically generate the class which measures the time. It needs to create a new class (with its own .java file ofc) that has those methods wrapped as in the example above. It should work for every non final class.

Comment: @M.Byenkov Let me know if this is what you are looking for and I can add some explanation.

Comment: Is this an inheritance question? When you say "wrapper", do you mean a child class that extends a parent, then calls methods of the parent/super class?

Comment: @Lucien Stals Not exactly an inheritance one. I just couldn't find any other way to call the function from the object of the first class. An object of the new, dynamically generated class (say class B) should  measure and write down the time which passed while methods of class A were working.

Comment: Quick update: After reading a little bit about proxy as @Matthew McPeak suggested I think it may come useful. Seems like a good solution but I don't know how to implement it yet.

Comment: It'd be perfect except for your requirement to generate source code.  I don't understand that requirement.  In industry -- that's the type of requirement that would get dropped (because it adds nothing to the run-time functionality and it makes the implementation ten times harder).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will use the `String` class as an example.

#### Wrapper method

```
 public static void getClassToWrap(Class<?> cls) {
    try {
        Object obj = cls.newInstance();
        obj = "helloWorld";
        Method reflectedMethod = cls.getDeclaredMethod("hashCode");
        System.out.println(reflectedMethod.invoke(obj));
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("stack trace");
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

#### timer method

```
public static long getMethodTimes(Class c) {
        long startTime = currentTimeMillis();
        getClassToWrap(c);
        System.out.println("Time passed = " + (currentTimeMillis() - startTime));
        System.out.println(startTime);
        return startTime;
    }
```

executed in `main method()` using `getMethodTimes(String.class);`

Edit in Response to OP

[How can I dynamically create a new .java file from a Java program?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4766716/how-can-i-dynamically-create-a-new-java-file-from-a-java-program)

> You cannot create new classes or methods using the reflection APIs.
> They are not designed for this. (The Class and Method APIs are for
> performing operations on object instances in a dynamic fashion.)
>
> If you want to create new code on the fly, there are two basic
> approaches to doing this:
>
> Generate Java source code, write it to a file, use the Java compiler
> to compile it to a bytecode file, and then load the bytecodes. (There
> are standard APIs for running the Java compiler within the JVM of a
> running application.)
>
> Use BCEL or equivalent to construct a bytecode file from scratch, and
> then load the bytecodes.
>
> Both approaches are tricky and computationally expensive. The BCEL
> approach is particularly tricky because you need to understand a lot
> about the JVM to do the job.

Comment: That is similiar to what I wanted, one difference is that I have to create a completely new .java file for the new class (that has the same set of methods as the basic one). An object of the new class (that may inherit from the base) should count the time for all the inherited methods. It's basicly just the old class extended by a timer for each of its methods.

Answer (score 0):

Just call `super` on the original class.

```
class Original
{
    public int add(int a, int b)
    {
        return a+b;
    }
}

class Wrapper extends Original
{
    public int add(int a, int b)
    {
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        int r = super.add(a,a);
        System.out.println("Time passed = " + System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime);
        return r;
    }   
}
```

Comment: The only issue I have with your solution is that Wrapper should not be the wrapped class itself. It should create a new class file (WrappedOriginal.java) that has all the functionalities of class Original (same interface) but also measures time. I tried with class.getName() and then writing it in with printwriter but I have no idea on how to get names of arguments in different methods.